# Is GeoTrust one of the trusted root certificates in Android => 2.3?

Tags: android, ssl, certificate

I'm googling an searching the web, but cannot really find a list of trusted root certificates on Android.

However, it seems like the list gets updated for each new version of Android.

What i need to know is:
Is GeoTrust a trusted root certificate in Android?
According to this site: http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2010/09/23/android-root-certification-authorities-list/   ,
Android 2.2 does not have GeoTrust as a trusted root certificate.

But is it in Android =>2.3 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

grepping `/system/etc/security/cacerts` (or looking into Settings > security) shows me those on my 4.0.3 device:

```
Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., OU=(c) 2007 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G2
Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA 2
Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Universal CA 2
Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority
Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3
Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Universal CA
```

Edit: grepping in strings in `cacerts.bks` from my 2.3.3 phone I get those:

```
GeoTrust Inc.1
GeoTrust Global CA0
GeoTrust Inc.1
GeoTrust Global CA0
GeoTrust Inc.1
GeoTrust Global CA 20
GeoTrust Inc.1
GeoTrust Global CA 20
GeoTrust Inc.1
GeoTrust Universal CA0
GeoTrust Inc.1
GeoTrust Universal CA0
GeoTrust Inc.110/
(GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority0
GeoTrust Inc.110/
(GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority0
GeoTrust Inc.1 0
GeoTrust Universal CA 20
GeoTrust Inc.1 0
GeoTrust Universal CA 20
```

Comment: ok, thanks... it gives a small indication that it exists on 2.3. But it would be good to clearify it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for Android 2.3 and above. Yes with cross root intermediate certificate, for Android 2.2 and below.

Reference: http://www.geocerts.com/ssl/browsers